# Constructible set which contains no closed points contradicts to the Nullstellensatz

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading the proof of this lemma:

[image]

I can't see why a non-empty constructible set which contains no closed points contradicts to the
Nullstellensatz. Is there a specific Nullstellensatz used here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $E$ be a nonempty and constructible subset of a scheme $Y$ of finite type over $k$. Since $Y$ is noetherian, we have

$$E = \bigcup_{i=1}^nF_i\cap U_i$$

where $F_i$ is closed in $Y$ and $U_i$ is open in $Y$ for every $i=1,...,n$. Since $E$ is nonempty, we derive that $F_{i_0}\cap U_{i_0}$ is nonempty for some $i_0$. Next every open subset of $Y$ can be covered by open affine subsets. Hence there exists an open affine subset $V\subseteq U_{i_0}$ such that $F_{i_0}\cap V$ is nonempty. Now $V = \mathrm{Spec} A$ for some finitely generated $k$-algebra $A$ and $F_{i_0}\cap V\subseteq V$ is a closed subset of $V$. By **Nullstellensatz** nonempty closed subset $F_{i_0}\cap V$ contains a closed point of $V$. Clearly 
$$F_{i_0}\cap V\subseteq F_{i_0}\cap U_{i_0}\subseteq E$$
and closed points of $V$ are $k$-rational. Thus $E$ contains $k$-rational point of $Y$.